# FB mobile canvas app/game redirection to external website

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook app built with canvas. We have made the app playable thru the Gamesroom via browser. I am aware that FB has deprecated support for Canvas applications on the mobile FB native app. I would like for when people click my app via mobile FB native app (android for now) to be redirected to a certain domain (web browser version of the game). Is it possible to do this, if so how can we?

Comment: Explain what exactly you mean by “when people click my app”.

Comment: Let me demonstrate using a screenshot:
https://ibb.co/DCRjtbM

Comment: The settings for the “Facebook Web Games” platform allow to specify a Mobile Site URL, that mobile users clicking on the link should be redirected to. (A while back this was abused by spammers somehow, so they implemented some sort of process where you explicitly had to get your Mobile Site URL white-listed or something like that, not sure if that is still the case.)